# Region select not showing in checkout after upgrade to Magento 2.4

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, knockoutjs, country-regions, missing

Are in the process of upgrading from M2.3.5 to the current version of Magento - 2.4.3

However, after having done so the Region select dropdown no longer appears in the checkout (on either billing or shipping address)

Have dug through the database comparing eav_attribute, eav_entity_type, customer_eav_attribute & customer_eav_attribute_website settings on our upgraded store against a vanilla Magento 2.4.3 store where region picker DOES show, and I can't see any difference.

Inspecting the code on the checkout page, I can see that divs for both region AND region_id are created BUT they both have display: none set inline  (Checking the vanilla store, and region shows like this there as well.)

[image]

If I set display: block, then I can see a Region select, but it doesn't have any option in it - I guess because knockout doesn't see it on page load.

So, does anyone know WHY this field isn't being displayed?  Or have any ideas on where I can check to find a reason?

The problem occurs using a blank theme, luma, or our custom one and so isn't related to that.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

OK, will leave this up here in case anyone is having as bad a day as me...

The issue was that for some reason the settings in:

Stores > Config > General > State Options

got lost during the upgrade

Reinstating mandatory state for the appropriate countries reintroduced the dropdown

(had completely forgotten about this aspect of the config)

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue.